# DirectCast any window, not only main window?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, window, directcast

I've been trying to edit variables in other windows like in VB.NET using DirectCast. This seems to be working very well with the main window, as I use

```
Private Main As MainWindow = DirectCast(Application.Current.MainWindow, MainWindow)
```

But, I am unable to find a way to use this with a window other than the main one. For now, I am stuck using this

```
Dim WindowOne As New Window1
WindowOne.Show()
```

This works, but I would rather not have to create a new instance of the window each time I want it to open. I have tried using

```
Private WindowOne As Window1 = DirectCast(Application.Current.Windows.OfType(Of Window1).First(), Window1)
```

but it always gives me an error saying that "The sequence contains no elements".

Is there any other way to do this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not cast it as a `Window`?

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå - I get the message 'Window is a type and cannot be used as an expression' when I try to cast it as a `Window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is below.

```
Private WindowOne As Window1 = Application.Current.Windows.OfType(Of Window1)().FirstOrDefault()
If Not WindowOne Is Nothing Then
  'object is available here
End If
```